# When I switch back and forth between views, my viewDidLoad is not being called a second time?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, viewdidload

So I have two views.  One views loads when I start the app.  Then when I press a button on that view it loads a another view.

```
- (IBAction)triggerGame
{

leveldata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[leveldata setValue:@"hide" forKey:@"shootarrow"];

[leveldata writeToFile:[self levelFilePath] atomically:YES];
[leveldata release];


Papertoss_MaraAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (Papertoss_MaraAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[mainDelegate playGame];

}
```

This action triggers a method in the delegate implementation called playGame, which looks like this:

```
- (void)playGame {

[levelView.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.window addSubview:[gameView view]];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This loads the new view just fine.  Then I have another button that does the same exact thing, but it brings me back to the first view.  And it too, works great.  I am able to navigate from one view to the other very easily.  But the only problem I have, is when I try load the second view a second time, the viewDidLoad is not called again.  I tested this by having an NSLog() in the viewDidLoad method.

For my app to do what I want I need the viewDidLoad to be called again.  I'm guessing maybe my view isn't fully unloaded when I switch between them.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need the function viewDidAppear. viewDidLoad only gets called once per view unless something causes it to unload, such as a memory warning. viewDidAppear gets called every time that view becomes visible.

Comment: What if I need to unload it, because I wanted it to load up different layers depending on which button I press.  How would I do that?

Comment: I don't think releasing the view is the best solution in this case, it could deallocate all that memory then has to reallocate and initialize a new view later

Comment: Yea I know its not the best solution, but I would like to know how to do it.  How exactly do I release it?  Or maybe I should be asking where should I release it.

Comment: I got it all figured out.  Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 4):

You want -viewDidAppear: for "every time the view is shown" stuff.